# Can you create a policy/rule or group which will limit an LDAP search to group of OUs?

Tags: ldap

I am new to using LDAP queries.  I have Active Directory running and a tree structured as:

Building1
 -Staff
 -Students
Building2
 -Staff
 -Students

I'm setting up LDAP queries on various systems and would like to limit the search results to just the staff OU's and exclude Students.  Is this possible with this structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's done in the filter, not via a rule/policy/group.

It's a poor way to structure the directory. What if someone moves to the other building? It would be better to have the buildings as groups that the staff or student are members of.

Comment: I have to sync with google apps and assign google policies to each "ou" within google.. sux